# Enumerate prints without using print inside loop

Tags: python-3.x, ascii, enumerate

After running this code. why are all these numbers being printed even though i haven't printed them. I think enumerate returns all these . If yes, then is there any way I can stop these.

```
def primeOrNot(num):
    count = 0
    for i in range (num-1, 1, -1):
        print(i,num)
        if(num%i==0):
            count=1
    if (count==0):
        return True
    else: return False

def nearest_prime(num):
    nearest = 0
    farthest = 0
    for i in range(num+1,256):
        if primeOrNot(i):
            farthest = i
            break
    for i in range(num-1,1,-1):
        if primeOrNot(i):
            nearest = i
            break
    nearest_dist = num - nearest
    farthest_dist = farthest - num
    if(farthest_dist>nearest_dist):
        return nearest
    elif (nearest_dist>farthest_dist):
        return farthest
    elif(nearest_dist==farthest_dist):
        return nearest

def main_code(test_case_no):
    for tn in range(0,test_case_no):
        str_len = input()
        input_str = input()
        input_list = [ord(i) for i in input_str]

        for index,num in enumerate(input_list):       #error here
            if not primeOrNot(num):
                input_list[index]=nearest_prime(num)
        ouput_list = [chr(i) for i in input_list]
        output_str = "".join(ouput_list)
        print(output_str)

test_case_no = int(input())
main_code(test_case_no)
```

Input:

```
1
6
AFREEN
```

Expected output :

```
CGSCCO
```

Actual output:-

```
64 65
63 65
62 65
61 65
60 65
59 65
58 65
57 65
56 65
55 65
54 65
53 65
52 65
51 65
50 65
49 65
48 65
47 65
46 65
45 65
44 65
43 65
42 65
41 65
40 65
39 65
38 65
37 65
36 65
35 65
34 65
33 65
32 65
31 65
30 65
29 65
28 65
27 65
26 65
25 65
24 65
23 65
22 65
21 65
20 65
19 65
18 65
17 65
16 65
15 65
14 65
13 65
12 65
11 65
10 65
9 65
8 65
7 65
6 65
5 65
4 65
3 65
2 65
65 66
64 66
63 66
62 66
61 66
60 66
59 66
58 66
57 66
56 66
55 66
54 66
53 66
52 66
51 66
50 66
49 66
48 66
47 66
46 66
45 66
44 66
43 66
42 66
41 66
40 66
39 66
38 66
37 66
36 66
35 66
34 66
33 66
32 66
31 66
30 66
29 66
28 66
27 66
26 66
25 66
24 66
23 66
22 66
21 66
20 66
19 66
18 66
17 66
16 66
15 66
14 66
13 66
12 66
11 66
10 66
9 66
8 66
7 66
6 66
5 66
4 66
3 66
2 66
66 67
65 67
64 67
63 67
62 67
61 67
60 67
59 67
58 67
57 67
56 67
55 67
54 67
53 67
52 67
51 67
50 67
49 67
48 67
47 67
46 67
45 67
44 67
43 67
42 67
41 67
40 67
39 67
38 67
37 67
36 67
35 67
34 67
33 67
32 67
31 67
30 67
29 67
28 67
27 67
26 67
25 67
24 67
23 67
22 67
21 67
20 67
19 67
18 67
17 67
16 67
15 67
14 67
13 67
12 67
11 67
10 67
9 67
8 67
7 67
6 67
5 67
4 67
3 67
2 67
63 64
62 64
61 64
60 64
59 64
58 64
57 64
56 64
55 64
54 64
53 64
52 64
51 64
50 64
49 64
48 64
47 64
46 64
45 64
44 64
43 64
42 64
41 64
40 64
39 64
38 64
37 64
36 64
35 64
34 64
33 64
32 64
31 64
30 64
29 64
28 64
27 64
26 64
25 64
24 64
23 64
22 64
21 64
20 64
19 64
18 64
17 64
16 64
15 64
14 64
13 64
12 64
11 64
10 64
9 64
8 64
7 64
6 64
5 64
4 64
3 64
2 64
62 63
61 63
60 63
59 63
58 63
57 63
56 63
55 63
54 63
53 63
52 63
51 63
50 63
49 63
48 63
47 63
46 63
45 63
44 63
43 63
42 63
41 63
40 63
39 63
38 63
37 63
36 63
35 63
34 63
33 63
32 63
31 63
30 63
29 63
28 63
27 63
26 63
25 63
24 63
23 63
22 63
21 63
20 63
19 63
18 63
17 63
16 63
15 63
14 63
13 63
12 63
11 63
10 63
9 63
8 63
7 63
6 63
5 63
4 63
3 63
2 63
61 62
60 62
59 62
58 62
57 62
56 62
55 62
54 62
53 62
52 62
51 62
50 62
49 62
48 62
47 62
46 62
45 62
44 62
43 62
42 62
41 62
40 62
39 62
38 62
37 62
36 62
35 62
34 62
33 62
32 62
31 62
30 62
29 62
28 62
27 62
26 62
25 62
24 62
23 62
22 62
21 62
20 62
19 62
18 62
17 62
16 62
15 62
14 62
13 62
12 62
11 62
10 62
9 62
8 62
7 62
6 62
5 62
4 62
3 62
2 62
60 61
59 61
58 61
57 61
56 61
55 61
54 61
53 61
52 61
51 61
50 61
49 61
48 61
47 61
46 61
45 61
44 61
43 61
42 61
41 61
40 61
39 61
38 61
37 61
36 61
35 61
34 61
33 61
32 61
31 61
30 61
29 61
28 61
27 61
26 61
25 61
24 61
23 61
22 61
21 61
20 61
19 61
18 61
17 61
16 61
15 61
14 61
13 61
12 61
11 61
10 61
9 61
8 61
7 61
6 61
5 61
4 61
3 61
2 61
69 70
68 70
67 70
66 70
65 70
64 70
63 70
62 70
61 70
60 70
59 70
58 70
57 70
56 70
55 70
54 70
53 70
52 70
51 70
50 70
49 70
48 70
47 70
46 70
45 70
44 70
43 70
42 70
41 70
40 70
39 70
38 70
37 70
36 70
35 70
34 70
33 70
32 70
31 70
30 70
29 70
28 70
27 70
26 70
25 70
24 70
23 70
22 70
21 70
20 70
19 70
18 70
17 70
16 70
15 70
14 70
13 70
12 70
11 70
10 70
9 70
8 70
7 70
6 70
5 70
4 70
3 70
2 70
70 71
69 71
68 71
67 71
66 71
65 71
64 71
63 71
62 71
61 71
60 71
59 71
58 71
57 71
56 71
55 71
54 71
53 71
52 71
51 71
50 71
49 71
48 71
47 71
46 71
45 71
44 71
43 71
42 71
41 71
40 71
39 71
38 71
37 71
36 71
35 71
34 71
33 71
32 71
31 71
30 71
29 71
28 71
27 71
26 71
25 71
24 71
23 71
22 71
21 71
20 71
19 71
18 71
17 71
16 71
15 71
14 71
13 71
12 71
11 71
10 71
9 71
8 71
7 71
6 71
5 71
4 71
3 71
2 71
68 69
67 69
66 69
65 69
64 69
63 69
62 69
61 69
60 69
59 69
58 69
57 69
56 69
55 69
54 69
53 69
52 69
51 69
50 69
49 69
48 69
47 69
46 69
45 69
44 69
43 69
42 69
41 69
40 69
39 69
38 69
37 69
36 69
35 69
34 69
33 69
32 69
31 69
30 69
29 69
28 69
27 69
26 69
25 69
24 69
23 69
22 69
21 69
20 69
19 69
18 69
17 69
16 69
15 69
14 69
13 69
12 69
11 69
10 69
9 69
8 69
7 69
6 69
5 69
4 69
3 69
2 69
67 68
66 68
65 68
64 68
63 68
62 68
61 68
60 68
59 68
58 68
57 68
56 68
55 68
54 68
53 68
52 68
51 68
50 68
49 68
48 68
47 68
46 68
45 68
44 68
43 68
42 68
41 68
40 68
39 68
38 68
37 68
36 68
35 68
34 68
33 68
32 68
31 68
30 68
29 68
28 68
27 68
26 68
25 68
24 68
23 68
22 68
21 68
20 68
19 68
18 68
17 68
16 68
15 68
14 68
13 68
12 68
11 68
10 68
9 68
8 68
7 68
6 68
5 68
4 68
3 68
2 68
66 67
65 67
64 67
63 67
62 67
61 67
60 67
59 67
58 67
57 67
56 67
55 67
54 67
53 67
52 67
51 67
50 67
49 67
48 67
47 67
46 67
45 67
44 67
43 67
42 67
41 67
40 67
39 67
38 67
37 67
36 67
35 67
34 67
33 67
32 67
31 67
30 67
29 67
28 67
27 67
26 67
25 67
24 67
23 67
22 67
21 67
20 67
19 67
18 67
17 67
16 67
15 67
14 67
13 67
12 67
11 67
10 67
9 67
8 67
7 67
6 67
5 67
4 67
3 67
2 67
81 82
80 82
79 82
78 82
77 82
76 82
75 82
74 82
73 82
72 82
71 82
70 82
69 82
68 82
67 82
66 82
65 82
64 82
63 82
62 82
61 82
60 82
59 82
58 82
57 82
56 82
55 82
54 82
53 82
52 82
51 82
50 82
49 82
48 82
47 82
46 82
45 82
44 82
43 82
42 82
41 82
40 82
39 82
38 82
37 82
36 82
35 82
34 82
33 82
32 82
31 82
30 82
29 82
28 82
27 82
26 82
25 82
24 82
23 82
22 82
21 82
20 82
19 82
18 82
17 82
16 82
15 82
14 82
13 82
12 82
11 82
10 82
9 82
8 82
7 82
6 82
5 82
4 82
3 82
2 82
82 83
81 83
80 83
79 83
78 83
77 83
76 83
75 83
74 83
73 83
72 83
71 83
70 83
69 83
68 83
67 83
66 83
65 83
64 83
63 83
62 83
61 83
60 83
59 83
58 83
57 83
56 83
55 83
54 83
53 83
52 83
51 83
50 83
49 83
48 83
47 83
46 83
45 83
44 83
43 83
42 83
41 83
40 83
39 83
38 83
37 83
36 83
35 83
34 83
33 83
32 83
31 83
30 83
29 83
28 83
27 83
26 83
25 83
24 83
23 83
22 83
21 83
20 83
19 83
18 83
17 83
16 83
15 83
14 83
13 83
12 83
11 83
10 83
9 83
8 83
7 83
6 83
5 83
4 83
3 83
2 83
80 81
79 81
78 81
77 81
76 81
75 81
74 81
73 81
72 81
71 81
70 81
69 81
68 81
67 81
66 81
65 81
64 81
63 81
62 81
61 81
60 81
59 81
58 81
57 81
56 81
55 81
54 81
53 81
52 81
51 81
50 81
49 81
48 81
47 81
46 81
45 81
44 81
43 81
42 81
41 81
40 81
39 81
38 81
37 81
36 81
35 81
34 81
33 81
32 81
31 81
30 81
29 81
28 81
27 81
26 81
25 81
24 81
23 81
22 81
21 81
20 81
19 81
18 81
17 81
16 81
15 81
14 81
13 81
12 81
11 81
10 81
9 81
8 81
7 81
6 81
5 81
4 81
3 81
2 81
79 80
78 80
77 80
76 80
75 80
74 80
73 80
72 80
71 80
70 80
69 80
68 80
67 80
66 80
65 80
64 80
63 80
62 80
61 80
60 80
59 80
58 80
57 80
56 80
55 80
54 80
53 80
52 80
51 80
50 80
49 80
48 80
47 80
46 80
45 80
44 80
43 80
42 80
41 80
40 80
39 80
38 80
37 80
36 80
35 80
34 80
33 80
32 80
31 80
30 80
29 80
28 80
27 80
26 80
25 80
24 80
23 80
22 80
21 80
20 80
19 80
18 80
17 80
16 80
15 80
14 80
13 80
12 80
11 80
10 80
9 80
8 80
7 80
6 80
5 80
4 80
3 80
2 80
78 79
77 79
76 79
75 79
74 79
73 79
72 79
71 79
70 79
69 79
68 79
67 79
66 79
65 79
64 79
63 79
62 79
61 79
60 79
59 79
58 79
57 79
56 79
55 79
54 79
53 79
52 79
51 79
50 79
49 79
48 79
47 79
46 79
45 79
44 79
43 79
42 79
41 79
40 79
39 79
38 79
37 79
36 79
35 79
34 79
33 79
32 79
31 79
30 79
29 79
28 79
27 79
26 79
25 79
24 79
23 79
22 79
21 79
20 79
19 79
18 79
17 79
16 79
15 79
14 79
13 79
12 79
11 79
10 79
9 79
8 79
7 79
6 79
5 79
4 79
3 79
2 79
68 69
67 69
66 69
65 69
64 69
63 69
62 69
61 69
60 69
59 69
58 69
57 69
56 69
55 69
54 69
53 69
52 69
51 69
50 69
49 69
48 69
47 69
46 69
45 69
44 69
43 69
42 69
41 69
40 69
39 69
38 69
37 69
36 69
35 69
34 69
33 69
32 69
31 69
30 69
29 69
28 69
27 69
26 69
25 69
24 69
23 69
22 69
21 69
20 69
19 69
18 69
17 69
16 69
15 69
14 69
13 69
12 69
11 69
10 69
9 69
8 69
7 69
6 69
5 69
4 69
3 69
2 69
69 70
68 70
67 70
66 70
65 70
64 70
63 70
62 70
61 70
60 70
59 70
58 70
57 70
56 70
55 70
54 70
53 70
52 70
51 70
50 70
49 70
48 70
47 70
46 70
45 70
44 70
43 70
42 70
41 70
40 70
39 70
38 70
37 70
36 70
35 70
34 70
33 70
32 70
31 70
30 70
29 70
28 70
27 70
26 70
25 70
24 70
23 70
22 70
21 70
20 70
19 70
18 70
17 70
16 70
15 70
14 70
13 70
12 70
11 70
10 70
9 70
8 70
7 70
6 70
5 70
4 70
3 70
2 70
70 71
69 71
68 71
67 71
66 71
65 71
64 71
63 71
62 71
61 71
60 71
59 71
58 71
57 71
56 71
55 71
54 71
53 71
52 71
51 71
50 71
49 71
48 71
47 71
46 71
45 71
44 71
43 71
42 71
41 71
40 71
39 71
38 71
37 71
36 71
35 71
34 71
33 71
32 71
31 71
30 71
29 71
28 71
27 71
26 71
25 71
24 71
23 71
22 71
21 71
20 71
19 71
18 71
17 71
16 71
15 71
14 71
13 71
12 71
11 71
10 71
9 71
8 71
7 71
6 71
5 71
4 71
3 71
2 71
67 68
66 68
65 68
64 68
63 68
62 68
61 68
60 68
59 68
58 68
57 68
56 68
55 68
54 68
53 68
52 68
51 68
50 68
49 68
48 68
47 68
46 68
45 68
44 68
43 68
42 68
41 68
40 68
39 68
38 68
37 68
36 68
35 68
34 68
33 68
32 68
31 68
30 68
29 68
28 68
27 68
26 68
25 68
24 68
23 68
22 68
21 68
20 68
19 68
18 68
17 68
16 68
15 68
14 68
13 68
12 68
11 68
10 68
9 68
8 68
7 68
6 68
5 68
4 68
3 68
2 68
66 67
65 67
64 67
63 67
62 67
61 67
60 67
59 67
58 67
57 67
56 67
55 67
54 67
53 67
52 67
51 67
50 67
49 67
48 67
47 67
46 67
45 67
44 67
43 67
42 67
41 67
40 67
39 67
38 67
37 67
36 67
35 67
34 67
33 67
32 67
31 67
30 67
29 67
28 67
27 67
26 67
25 67
24 67
23 67
22 67
21 67
20 67
19 67
18 67
17 67
16 67
15 67
14 67
13 67
12 67
11 67
10 67
9 67
8 67
7 67
6 67
5 67
4 67
3 67
2 67
68 69
67 69
66 69
65 69
64 69
63 69
62 69
61 69
60 69
59 69
58 69
57 69
56 69
55 69
54 69
53 69
52 69
51 69
50 69
49 69
48 69
47 69
46 69
45 69
44 69
43 69
42 69
41 69
40 69
39 69
38 69
37 69
36 69
35 69
34 69
33 69
32 69
31 69
30 69
29 69
28 69
27 69
26 69
25 69
24 69
23 69
22 69
21 69
20 69
19 69
18 69
17 69
16 69
15 69
14 69
13 69
12 69
11 69
10 69
9 69
8 69
7 69
6 69
5 69
4 69
3 69
2 69
69 70
68 70
67 70
66 70
65 70
64 70
63 70
62 70
61 70
60 70
59 70
58 70
57 70
56 70
55 70
54 70
53 70
52 70
51 70
50 70
49 70
48 70
47 70
46 70
45 70
44 70
43 70
42 70
41 70
40 70
39 70
38 70
37 70
36 70
35 70
34 70
33 70
32 70
31 70
30 70
29 70
28 70
27 70
26 70
25 70
24 70
23 70
22 70
21 70
20 70
19 70
18 70
17 70
16 70
15 70
14 70
13 70
12 70
11 70
10 70
9 70
8 70
7 70
6 70
5 70
4 70
3 70
2 70
70 71
69 71
68 71
67 71
66 71
65 71
64 71
63 71
62 71
61 71
60 71
59 71
58 71
57 71
56 71
55 71
54 71
53 71
52 71
51 71
50 71
49 71
48 71
47 71
46 71
45 71
44 71
43 71
42 71
41 71
40 71
39 71
38 71
37 71
36 71
35 71
34 71
33 71
32 71
31 71
30 71
29 71
28 71
27 71
26 71
25 71
24 71
23 71
22 71
21 71
20 71
19 71
18 71
17 71
16 71
15 71
14 71
13 71
12 71
11 71
10 71
9 71
8 71
7 71
6 71
5 71
4 71
3 71
2 71
67 68
66 68
65 68
64 68
63 68
62 68
61 68
60 68
59 68
58 68
57 68
56 68
55 68
54 68
53 68
52 68
51 68
50 68
49 68
48 68
47 68
46 68
45 68
44 68
43 68
42 68
41 68
40 68
39 68
38 68
37 68
36 68
35 68
34 68
33 68
32 68
31 68
30 68
29 68
28 68
27 68
26 68
25 68
24 68
23 68
22 68
21 68
20 68
19 68
18 68
17 68
16 68
15 68
14 68
13 68
12 68
11 68
10 68
9 68
8 68
7 68
6 68
5 68
4 68
3 68
2 68
66 67
65 67
64 67
63 67
62 67
61 67
60 67
59 67
58 67
57 67
56 67
55 67
54 67
53 67
52 67
51 67
50 67
49 67
48 67
47 67
46 67
45 67
44 67
43 67
42 67
41 67
40 67
39 67
38 67
37 67
36 67
35 67
34 67
33 67
32 67
31 67
30 67
29 67
28 67
27 67
26 67
25 67
24 67
23 67
22 67
21 67
20 67
19 67
18 67
17 67
16 67
15 67
14 67
13 67
12 67
11 67
10 67
9 67
8 67
7 67
6 67
5 67
4 67
3 67
2 67
77 78
76 78
75 78
74 78
73 78
72 78
71 78
70 78
69 78
68 78
67 78
66 78
65 78
64 78
63 78
62 78
61 78
60 78
59 78
58 78
57 78
56 78
55 78
54 78
53 78
52 78
51 78
50 78
49 78
48 78
47 78
46 78
45 78
44 78
43 78
42 78
41 78
40 78
39 78
38 78
37 78
36 78
35 78
34 78
33 78
32 78
31 78
30 78
29 78
28 78
27 78
26 78
25 78
24 78
23 78
22 78
21 78
20 78
19 78
18 78
17 78
16 78
15 78
14 78
13 78
12 78
11 78
10 78
9 78
8 78
7 78
6 78
5 78
4 78
3 78
2 78
78 79
77 79
76 79
75 79
74 79
73 79
72 79
71 79
70 79
69 79
68 79
67 79
66 79
65 79
64 79
63 79
62 79
61 79
60 79
59 79
58 79
57 79
56 79
55 79
54 79
53 79
52 79
51 79
50 79
49 79
48 79
47 79
46 79
45 79
44 79
43 79
42 79
41 79
40 79
39 79
38 79
37 79
36 79
35 79
34 79
33 79
32 79
31 79
30 79
29 79
28 79
27 79
26 79
25 79
24 79
23 79
22 79
21 79
20 79
19 79
18 79
17 79
16 79
15 79
14 79
13 79
12 79
11 79
10 79
9 79
8 79
7 79
6 79
5 79
4 79
3 79
2 79
76 77
75 77
74 77
73 77
72 77
71 77
70 77
69 77
68 77
67 77
66 77
65 77
64 77
63 77
62 77
61 77
60 77
59 77
58 77
57 77
56 77
55 77
54 77
53 77
52 77
51 77
50 77
49 77
48 77
47 77
46 77
45 77
44 77
43 77
42 77
41 77
40 77
39 77
38 77
37 77
36 77
35 77
34 77
33 77
32 77
31 77
30 77
29 77
28 77
27 77
26 77
25 77
24 77
23 77
22 77
21 77
20 77
19 77
18 77
17 77
16 77
15 77
14 77
13 77
12 77
11 77
10 77
9 77
8 77
7 77
6 77
5 77
4 77
3 77
2 77
75 76
74 76
73 76
72 76
71 76
70 76
69 76
68 76
67 76
66 76
65 76
64 76
63 76
62 76
61 76
60 76
59 76
58 76
57 76
56 76
55 76
54 76
53 76
52 76
51 76
50 76
49 76
48 76
47 76
46 76
45 76
44 76
43 76
42 76
41 76
40 76
39 76
38 76
37 76
36 76
35 76
34 76
33 76
32 76
31 76
30 76
29 76
28 76
27 76
26 76
25 76
24 76
23 76
22 76
21 76
20 76
19 76
18 76
17 76
16 76
15 76
14 76
13 76
12 76
11 76
10 76
9 76
8 76
7 76
6 76
5 76
4 76
3 76
2 76
74 75
73 75
72 75
71 75
70 75
69 75
68 75
67 75
66 75
65 75
64 75
63 75
62 75
61 75
60 75
59 75
58 75
57 75
56 75
55 75
54 75
53 75
52 75
51 75
50 75
49 75
48 75
47 75
46 75
45 75
44 75
43 75
42 75
41 75
40 75
39 75
38 75
37 75
36 75
35 75
34 75
33 75
32 75
31 75
30 75
29 75
28 75
27 75
26 75
25 75
24 75
23 75
22 75
21 75
20 75
19 75
18 75
17 75
16 75
15 75
14 75
13 75
12 75
11 75
10 75
9 75
8 75
7 75
6 75
5 75
4 75
3 75
2 75
73 74
72 74
71 74
70 74
69 74
68 74
67 74
66 74
65 74
64 74
63 74
62 74
61 74
60 74
59 74
58 74
57 74
56 74
55 74
54 74
53 74
52 74
51 74
50 74
49 74
48 74
47 74
46 74
45 74
44 74
43 74
42 74
41 74
40 74
39 74
38 74
37 74
36 74
35 74
34 74
33 74
32 74
31 74
30 74
29 74
28 74
27 74
26 74
25 74
24 74
23 74
22 74
21 74
20 74
19 74
18 74
17 74
16 74
15 74
14 74
13 74
12 74
11 74
10 74
9 74
8 74
7 74
6 74
5 74
4 74
3 74
2 74
72 73
71 73
70 73
69 73
68 73
67 73
66 73
65 73
64 73
63 73
62 73
61 73
60 73
59 73
58 73
57 73
56 73
55 73
54 73
53 73
52 73
51 73
50 73
49 73
48 73
47 73
46 73
45 73
44 73
43 73
42 73
41 73
40 73
39 73
38 73
37 73
36 73
35 73
34 73
33 73
32 73
31 73
30 73
29 73
28 73
27 73
26 73
25 73
24 73
23 73
22 73
21 73
20 73
19 73
18 73
17 73
16 73
15 73
14 73
13 73
12 73
11 73
10 73
9 73
8 73
7 73
6 73
5 73
4 73
3 73
2 73
CGSCCO
```

Note: Every pair of numbers are in new line in actual output.

Comment: remove `print(i,num)` inside `primeOrNot`

Comment: You print them in line 4 of your code...

Comment: Done!  Thanks @Rakesh .....mine Silly mistake...